# This is an invalid xsi:type 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides:Project'

Tags: office-addins, yeoman-generator, yeoman-generator-angular, office-store

I have used yeoman generator and built the **MS Project** Add-in using Angular Framework. Now I want to upload the manifest in Office 365 Admin portal to make it available within our organization.

When I run the `Office toolbox` aka `office validator` . I am getting the following error and ended up with validation error.

> XML Schema Violation: Your manifest does not adhere to the current set
>   of XML schema definitions for Office Add-in manifests.
>     - Details: This is an invalid xsi:type 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/taskpaneappversionoverrides:Project'.

[image]

I have tried generating a sample project using the latest version of yo office which is also failed in validation.

```
yo --version
3.1.0
```

Require help on this.

Answer (score 0):

I have interacted with MSFT support team. After a good long conversation I finally figured out yeoman generated XML is not accepted in App source due to `policy violations and overrides of element used`.

Below is the simple approach of Manifest If any one wants to publish their add-ins.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">
  <!-- IMPORTANT! Id must be unique for your add-in, if you reuse this manifest ensure that you change this id to a new GUID. Add your own below -->
  <Id>your Guid</Id>
  <!--Version. Updates from the store only get triggered if there is a version change. -->
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Your Company name</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <!-- The display name of your add-in. Used on the store and various places of the Office UI such as the add-ins dialog. -->
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Add-in"/>
  <Description
    DefaultValue="Short Description"/>
  <!-- Icon for your add-in. Used on installation screens and the add-ins dialog. -->
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="Iconurl.com"/>
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="Iconurl.com"/>
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://yourcompany.com/help"/>
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>yourcompany.com</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Project"/>
  </Hosts>
  <DefaultSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://yourcompany/index.html"/>
  </DefaultSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>
 </OfficeApp>
```

Please read the comments for better understanding. Hope it will help someone who wants to publish it to **AppSource**. Thanks